# Postfix block open relay mail from mynetworks

Tags: postfix

we're running postfix 3.1.4.  Found that some hosts in mynetworks may use our server as open relay, to send mail with sender@ and recipient@ where domainA and domainB are not local domains.

It's acceptable to have either sender or recipient on non-local domains but not both.

Would anyone please help?    Thanks a lot.

Regards,

/ST Wong

Comment: They don't really belong in `mynetworks` then, do they?

Answer (score 1):

You can limit relay only for certain domains, for example

```
smtpd_relay_restrictions = check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/permit_domain, defer_unauth_destination
```

permit only domains listed in file, file format is

```
mydomain.com OK
anotherdomain.com OK
```